# What is best type for profile image in user class?

Tags: android, image, file, bitmap, drawable

UserVo,java

```
public class UserVo extends MemberVo {

    protected String password;
    protected String phoneNumber;
    protected int level;

    // Profile Image
    protected CharSequence profileImagePath;
    protected Bitmap profileImageBitmap;
    protected Drawable profileImageDrawable;
    protected File profileImageFile;
}
```

I make app. I need to use profile image.

Origin image type is Bitmap. But I think bitmap occur memory leaks... (Right?)

So I save bitmap to File in storage.

What is best type for profile image in UserVo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't display a Bitmap directly in an Android App.You must create an ImageView and give it you Bitmap with the `setImageBitmap` method.